# sum crystal report different month

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008. And I have database access 2003 "myclass" with table "Class" an output of like this:

```
----------
Date                  Total
12/2015                100
01/2016                115
02/2016                150
03/2016                180
----------
```

Now, my question how formula for "Previous_Total" the output should be:

```
----------
Date                  Total        Previous_Total
12/2015                100              0  ----> 0 because no data before
01/2016                115              100   -----> this form total
02/2016                150              215   -----> 100 + 115
03/2016                180              365   -----> 100 + 115 + 150    
----------
```

if i'm use record selection ex sample: {Class.date}>=Date("02/2016") And {Class.date}<=Date("03/2016")
i want to show in the report like this:

```
----------

Date             Total         Previous_Total
02/2016           150               215

----------
```

Comment: Ok. So what is your question, actually? And what did you do towards answering it by yourself?

Comment: i want to know "previos total" with formula, because if i using selection formula: {Class.date}>=Date("01/2016")  and {Class.date}<=Date("02/2016") in the report cant show...

Comment: where did you use this formula?

Comment: after trying 3 day,  my case is done....

1. create group date as "In specified order" then setting to "is in the period " and im select AllDatesFromToday
2. create group total as "in ascending order"

Answer (score 0):

After trying 3 days,  my case is done....

1. create group Date as "In specified order" then setting to "is in the period " and I'm selecting AllDatesFromToday (Position group is down column Page Header).
2. create group Total as "in ascending order" (Position group is up column Details).
3. Hide column details
4. insert Summary Date as "Maximum"
5. insert summary Total as "Sum"
6. drag max total to group Date, drag sum total to group Date

Finally create formula Previous_Total:

```
 Sum ({MyClass.Total}, {MyClass.Date}, "daily")-{MyClass.Total}
```

Drag formula Previous_Total to group Date.

I try to test... Klik Menu Report, Selection Formulas, Record...

```
{MyClass.Date}<=date("02/2016")
```

Save, press F5 to refresh data and DONE...

Thank everybody for reply.... :)